# Why doesn't compiler make a virtual function non virtual when it is possible?

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, virtual-functions

```
class A{
     void virtual a(){}
};
int main() { 
    std::cout<<sizeof(A);
}
```

In the above case why doesn't the compiler make the function non virtual and save the space allocated to it. Is there a specific reason for not doing that?

I am using gcc 4.7 compiler, if it is compiler specific.

Comment: Because the compiler has no way of accurately determining whether you make use of the dynamic dispatch mechanism or not. It cannot assume you don't just by examining the current TU.

Comment: And on a related issue, it's worth noting that most compilers these days can inline a virtual function when it can be determined at compile time which overload of a virtual function is being called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you may create a derived class in a separate translation module.

In theory this could be resolved at link time, but this would involve a lot of work, so in practice that doesn't happen (AFAIK).

Comment: With dynamic libraries, not even LTO can rule out that subclasses may enter the picture. At least until LTO is applied to dynamic linkers too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler proper probably won't do this because it doesn't know what's in other files.

The linker might be able to do this, but there is no guarantee that a descendant version of A doesn't exist somewhere and will be loaded in a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure what you write is true? What is your proof in optimized build?

My observations are that if the program does contain code to create a single instance of A, then VMT is not linked with the program and the functions, including virtuals are not used either.

Comment: Yes, I ran the program and the output is 8

Comment: Yeah, but 8 what? Or did you actually mean the question on why pointer to VMT is included in the instance? If so please edit the question.

Comment: No, I meant what I posted.Anyway Oli Charlesworth already gave the answer.

Comment: so you think that 8 has any relation with the function a() in the class?

Comment: Yes, remove the 'virtual' and the output will be 1(as in empty class)

Comment: @banarun: The presence of a vtable pointer does not prove that a vtable exists, nor that a() is in that hypothetical vtable.